# How to check drive temperature on Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, ssd, temperature

I have used of `hdparm -n` and `smartctl -A` but it always seem to be a "per drive" technique as a drive may answer for only one of these tools.

So, is there a standard way to get the drive temperature on Linux (HDD or SSD)? If not, what (other) tools can I use to get this information?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I like [`hddtemp`](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/hddtemp/), which provides a pretty standard way of getting the temperature for supported devices. It requires SMART support though.

Example Usage: `sudo hddtemp /dev/sd[abcdefghi]`

Example Response:

> /dev/sda: WDC WD6401AALS-00J7B0: 31°C
> /dev/sdb: WDC WD7501AALS-00J7B0: 30°C

Comment: A shorter way would be hddtemp `/dev/sd?`.

Comment: `/dev/sd?` spares even more fingers.

Comment: Don't forget the `type` prefix (`PATA`/`SATA`/`SCSI`) for some devices; this 8-bay [UASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) tower needs the `SATA` prefix or else I don't get any temperatures: `sudo hddtemp SATA:/dev/sd{a..h}`

Comment: I'm getting `"drive supported, but it doesn't have a temperature sensor."` for every drive on my system, which is NOT true - the temps are reported in `smartctl`.

Comment: And how do you hide messages that do not have a temperature or are not supported?

Answer (score 5):

All SMART-capable devices should respond to `smartctl`. And I guss that only smart-devices have a temperature reading.

All other tools will propably be more or less vendor-specific (like Dell`s omsa). [IPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) might be another generic approach, but I doubt, that a temperature-reading of a storage-device is standard there.

Comment: Oh yeah, in general terms you can read the output of a thermistor using the cee language... it's like so obvious. (this answer is overly-generic)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Rovanion, to list all drives in one go:

```
hddtemp /dev/sd?
```

Or, if you prefer a for loop:

```
for i in /dev/sd[a-z]; do hddtemp "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# ls -1 /dev/sd? | xargs -n1 smartctl -A | grep Celsius
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   043   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       43 (0 25 0 0 0)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 18 0 0 0)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 21 0 0 0)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   046   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       46 (0 24 0 0 0)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   044   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       44 (0 25 0 0 0)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   044   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       44 (0 24 0 0 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try `watch "sensors && sudo hddtemp /dev/sd?"` which provides cpu and other temperature information in addition.

Comment: That's assuming lm-sensors is installed

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, I have added this line to `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias hddtemp='sudo hddtemp /dev/sd*[^[:digit:]] |sort -k3rn'
```

Now, one gets:

```
$ hddtemp
    /dev/sda: Generic MassStorageClass: S.M.A.R.T. not available
    /dev/sde: WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0: 35°C
    /dev/sdf: WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0: 34°C
    /dev/sdg: WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0: 36°C
```